# How to write shell script for creating zip ?

Tags: scripts, zip

I need to write a shell `script .sh` file which is creating a **zip** file from `/var/www` as a `sudo` user.

---

I have my Ubuntu server and my site hosted on it which means my source code is in `/var/www` folder. But `/var/www` has writeable permissions only for `root` user.

I want to write a script for backing up the `/var/www` folder as a **zip** every time I run that script with no need to ask root user password.

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AU**. What are you referring to as `"a sudo user"`? Executing part or including in shell script. :)

Comment: So you want the script to run as root? Are you looking for `if [ "$UID" != "0" ]; then echo not root; fi`?

Comment: I need shell script code, 
/var/www folder having only accessed by root user.

Comment: What does "/var/www folder having only accessed by root user" mean?

Comment: I will explain my complete requirement ::

I have my ubuntu server, and my site hosted on it, means my source code in /var/www folder. here /var/www folder writable permissions only for root user.

I want to write a script for backingup that (/var/www)folder as a zip when I run that script. (no need to ask root user password)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi & Welcome to **AskUbuntu**,

Well, I'm not sure why `/var/www` directory is been owned by root while technically it should be `www-data` who'll be the owner & the group as default. Nevertheless, the simplest way to achieve this is using below script which I use to compress some of my directories. I'm using `tar` command instead.

## Creating a shell script

- open a terminal (with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) & create a new bash file.
- type the command `nano filenam.sh` & paste below (alter the script according to your need).

```
#!/bin/bash 

TIME=`date +%F-%H%M%S`                   # time stamp to the backup file
FILENAME="backuup nam-$TIME.tar.gz"      # defining the format of the file name while backing up
SRCDIR="/home/parth/to/source"           # Location of the backup directory
DESDIR="/home/path/to/destination"       # Destination of the backup directory (where you need to backup)
tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR      # Executing the command
```

- save the script (with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> & enter). Then exit (with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).

## Executing the command

- Simply run `sudo sh filename.sh` to perform (sudo will run with root previledge)

You may also add this to a cronjob which will automate the process according to your needs. This bash script append a time stamp and backup on an incrimental basis. Its just a simple script that I took and altered to your ease.

Refer official *Ubuntu Documentation* on [**Shell Scripts**](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/backup-shellscripts.html) & bash script which I took from [**BroExperts**](http://www.broexperts.com/2012/06/how-to-backup-files-and-directories-in-linux-using-tar-cron-jobs/).

Hope it helps!